# Convert to Range VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Does anyone know how to "Convert to Range" in VBA code... I need to convert the "dam" table before applying a subtotal ...hhmmmm

Answer (score 4):

This should do the same as the *Convert to Range* function

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").Unlist
```

Comment: Excellent !  Works great...  Thanx!